# Find prime $p$ such that $(2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times ... \times p) + 1$ is not prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So far I only found a number through brute-forcing with wolframalpha ($p=13$). I'm stuck on finding an efficient method to either determine primality (using limited tools/what I know in the course so far) or to generate this number. Any hints?

Edit: typo

Edit2: Found a method that reduces the brute-forcing by checking only the primes that are greater than $p$ and less than $\sqrt {2 \times 3 \times ... \times p +1}$. This still makes you check more numbers than I’d like though to find p=13 (without any aids other than a calculator).

Edit3: ^The method above is actually not that too time-consuming. I roughly counted that it takes 22 checks total to see that $p=13$ works (when you exclude some examples that clearly don't work like $p=2,3,5$).

Comment: Did you mean $p=13$?

Comment: yes p=13 and the product is 30030

Comment: These are (together with the expressions *subtracting* one) called [primorial primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime).  You are correct that the smallest such expression which is composite (not prime) is $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdot 13 + 1$.  After that nonprimes in sequence become more frequent.

Comment: I believe that it is unknown if the number of primes in that sequence is finite.

Comment: @hardmath One of those conjectures I (re)discovered and was playing around with as a kid (before I learned they had a special name, primorial primes). Of course, I also considered the product minus one problem.

Comment: If you like, I'll post an answer addressing the methods used in current searches for such numbers, with links to the best known organized search for them.  The methods are not profoundly different from those applicable to many kinds of large numbers, but they have been studied fairly intensively over the past thirty years.

Comment: @hardmath sure, but I still want to make it relevant to my course so please nothing too beyond second year university level (or just add a disclaimer that such method is).

Comment: Why would you think there is any method other than brute force? It's not surprising that $2\cdot 3\cdot 5 + 1$ is prime because if it weren't it's prime factors must be more than $7$ but $2\cdot 3\cdot 5 + 1 < 7^9$. $11^2< 2\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot 7 + 1 <17^2$ so if it weren't prime it have to be $11^2, 11\cdot 13,$ or $13^2$ and it's "unlikely" any of those are true.  $13^2 < 47^2 < 13^3 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11+ 1< 53^2$ so there *many* more options and so that it might be a product of two or three primes greater than $11$ is likely but doesn't happen.

Comment: $17^2 <  173^2 <17^3 < 2*3*5*7*11*13+1  < 177^2$ so there are lot of options.

Comment: @fleablood I thought there was another method other than brute-forcing because it's a textbook question. Like I thought there was more to learn other than just doing an algorithm. And I previously thought that brute-forcing would simply take too long but I see now that it doesn't.

Comment: @fleablood I agree with your first statement but how does the fact $2 \times 3 \times 5 +1 < 7^9$ justify that?

Comment: The only prime factors of $2\times 3 \times 5 + 1 $ must be greater than $7$.  So if $2\times 3 \times 5 +1 = mn$ is composition then $n >7$ and $m > 7$ and then $2\times 3\times 5 + 1 = mn < 7\times 7$.  But $2\times 3\times 5 + 1 < 7^2$ so $2\times 3\times 5 + 1$ can not be compositie.

Comment: The primorials have been checked upto very high $p$ for primality. Heuristics predict infinite many primes of both kinds ($p$#$-1$ and $p$#$+1$) , in particular because prime factors of those numbers must exceed $p$, but of course it is open for both types whether this is actually the case.

Comment: There are much more efficient methods to check large numbers for primality than trial division. The most powerful test is probably the BPSW-test. Although infinite many counterexamples are expected to exist, NONE is known and it is claimed that the range upto $2^{64}$ works correct. "Composite" is a result always correct and "Prime" a result "almost always" correct.